# Detect Home wiring breakage

Tags: electrical, repair, electrical-panel

I am having a problem with my home **concealed** wiring . In two rooms i am having delay of 3-4 seconds to get power once the switch is on ( whether it is light, fan or power plug ) . Both these rooms are charged from a line that starts from main switch board  ( where distribution happens ) and comes to a **junction board** from where it is split to two rooms . I got my computer's motherboard (connected to power plug in one of the rooms )  faulty and the repairmen told it was due to power problem .

Is this problem due to breakage of connection wire ? If it is what is the best way to detect the breakage .

Comment: What country is this? What is the nature of the "junction board" that feeds the two rooms? Is it simply a connection of wires or does it have a transformer or surge protector or circuit breakers or any other electronic components?

Comment: Hi Jim , Junction board is just a connection of wires , It is the main board that have the surge protector and circuit breaker  ....... Its from India .

Answer (score 1):

A single strand copper wire used to connect between switches ( the positive terminals ) which broke and was causing the breakage . Replaced that with a stranded wire and problem solved . –

Comment: The single strand copper wire is called "solid" as in solid versus stranded. Good work finding the break, sometimes they can be intermittent.